# Loop na mysqli_query

Tags: php

Escrevi um programa que separa as palavras pelo espaço e registra cada um delas separadamente no banco de dados. Porém, na hora de colocar a *query* dentro do laço, ela não lê a variável por estar dentro dos parenteses da *string*. Podem me ajudar?

**Código:**

```
<?php
$poema = "Detesto seguir alguém assim como detesto conduzir. 
Obedecer? Não! E governar, nunca! 
Quem não se mete medo não consegue metê-lo a 
          ninguém, 
E só aquele que o inspira pode comandar. 
Já detesto guiar-me a mim próprio! 
Gosto, como os animais das florestas e dos mares, 
De me perder durante um grande pedaço, 
Acocorar-me a sonhar num deserto encantador, 
E forçar-me a regressar de longe aos meus penates, 
Atrair-me a mim próprio... para mim.";

$partido = explode(" ", $poema);

var_dump($partido);

echo count($partido);

$conn = mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','teste');

for ($i = 0; $i < $partido; $i++) {
    mysqli_query($conn, 'INSERT INTO teste (nome) VALUES ($partido[$i])');
}
```

Comment: pessoal o erro esta após o VALUES onde a variavel que acessa a array é identificada com um texto e n como a variavel!!! gratidao!

Comment: Utilize aspas quando for usar *query* dinâmicas. Ex.: `mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO teste (nome) VALUES ('{$partido[$i]}')");`

Comment: aaaaah LINDO n sabia mesmo!!! estou estudando vc foi um anjo gratiluz <3